# SQL Join along with conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a case where:

**Table 1:**

```
+------------+---------------+----------------------+
| Address_id |   road name   |        suburb        |
+------------+---------------+----------------------+
| 500011     | Bealey avenue | Christchurch Central |
+------------+---------------+----------------------+
```

**Table 2:**

```
+--------+------------------------------------------------+--------+
| Job_id |                  streets name                  | suburb |
+--------+------------------------------------------------+--------+
| 15678J | Bealey avenue, Salisbury Street, Gordon avenue |        |
+--------+------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

How can I write a SQL query to join the tables on two conditions:

1. The suburbs should match
2. The road name in `Table 1` (in this case Bealey avenue) should be there among others in the streets name column of the `Table 2`.

I need to join the two tables on conditions that, the suburb should match exactly in both and Road name "Bealey avenue" in `Table 1` should be there among other street names in `Table 2`.

Comment: First and foremost I would recommend re-thinking your design. Suburbs may be a separate table and then linked with an address. Your Table 2 structure is not clear, what is data and what is field and which data belongs to which field (except for the job id). Can you do a proper formatting on your question as mentioned in above comment please

Comment: which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I agree that you seem to suffer from a horrible table design. Don't store streets in a comma-separated string. Rather than muddling your way through this, you should change this database design, if you can.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind replies. Unfortunately its not the table which I created. But its the table available as part of my database given by the college.

Comment: Dear all, Thanks to Mr,Nimantha, my question is crystal clear now. Can someone help me now on this

Answer (score 0):

Although I wholeheartedly agree with the comments that you should avoid this table design if at all possible, here is a possible solution that you can use.

Example table set-up:

```
create table table1 (
    address_id int,
    road_name varchar(50),
    suburb varchar(50)
);

create table table2 (
    job_id varchar(50),
    streets_name varchar(250),
    suburb varchar(50)
);

insert into table1 
values (500011, 'Bealey avenue', 'Christchurch Central');

insert into table2
values ('15678J', 'Bealey avenue, Salisbury Street, Gordon avenue', 'Christchurch Central');
```

Query:

```
select * 
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on 
    t1.suburb = t2.suburb 
    and t2.streets_name REGEXP CONCAT('\\b', t1.road_name, '\\b')
```

[interact with the query here on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4U4XMMWooKqGof1gXVwwTV/0)

Comment: Thank you very much Kurt. This query works perfectly fine for bealey avenue alone. But in my case its just a part. The table 1  has other roads too and table 2 has around 500 rows of different rows with multiple streets. I'll make my point clear. I just have to right a query for joining the tables on conditions which 1) The suburb in Table1 matches suburb in Table 2 and 2) The road name in Table 1 should match anyone of the street names available in Table 2. The problem I encounter here is, the road name is just one/two worded names but there are multiple street names in table 2

Comment: You're welcome. If I understand you correctly, my solution above should cover most if not all cases of your problem. 

The `\\b` in the line `t2.streets_name REGEXP CONCAT('\\b', t1.road_name, '\\b')` represent word endings. Which means that there will only be a match if the full `t1.road_name` exists in `t2.streets_name`.

Have you tried adding more examples to the db-fiddle that I linked? 

And does the `streets_name` column from Table 2 always have 3 streets?

Answer (score 0):

Ypoun can use a inner join and your comparisons as ON clause

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table2 (Job_id  varchar(10) , streets_name varchar(200), suburb varchar(50))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('15678J','Bealey avenue, Salisbury Street, Gordon avenue','Christchurch Central')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1 (Address_id  varchar(10) , road_name varchar(200), suburb varchar(50))
> ```

> ```
>  INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('500011', 'Bealey avenue', 'Christchurch Central')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t2.* FROM Table2 t2 INNER JOIN Table1 t1 
> ON t1.suburb = t2.suburb AND INSTR(t2.streets_name,t1.road_name)> 0
> ```
>
> ```
> Job_id | streets_name                                   | suburb              
> :----- | :--------------------------------------------- | :-------------------
> 15678J | Bealey avenue, Salisbury Street, Gordon avenue | Christchurch Central
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c899f7e42338c38348761c435e5ae3f1)*